# Seeking Solutions: Preventing Unintended File Sharing via Signed URLs in S3/CloudFront System

Tags: nginx, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

I am currently designing a system utilizing Amazon S3 and CloudFront. As part of my access management strategy, the backend service generates a signed URL in communication with CloudFront/S3 and shares it with the end user. The end user is then expected to use this signed URL to retrieve the file.

My main challenge lies in preventing specific users from sharing the provided signed URL with other users. Such actions could potentially allow these other users to download the file, an occurrence I am trying to avoid. It's important to mention that the file in question is media-based. Therefore, I would prefer CloudFront to serve the file instead of my backend. If my backend was to handle the task, it would likely experience a heavy load, resulting in management difficulties.

I've been considering integrating a Lambda function into CloudFront, programmed to contact my backend with each request to verify user credentials. In this case, do I need to have a signed URL at all as all requests are evaluated by the Lambda function??? I am uncertain about the performance implications of this approach, as well as its alignment with best practices.

Moreover, I am curious about how CloudFront identifies which URL corresponds to which file, and how successful it is at caching these files. For instance, suppose we have two different users, each provided with a distinct signed URL, but both URLs point to the same physical file. I'm unsure whether CloudFront is capable of caching this file just once or if it ends up caching it twice. Any insights on this matter would be appreciated.

As a final question: Could CloudFront potentially be replaced by Nginx in the context of a private Content Delivery Network (CDN)? Does Nginx also support the generation of signed URLs and integration with serverless functions similar to AWS Lambda (for instance, for controlling user access to the target file)? Thanks.

Comment: Did you explore signed cookies? Read [Choosing between signed URLs and signed cookies](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/private-content-choosing-signed-urls-cookies.html)